# jquery find immediate parent of current element

Tags: jquery

how can  i get immediate parent of a given element ?

$(e.target).parent() ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$(element).parent()` returns the immediate parent.

```
$("#my-button").click(function() {
    var parentElement = $(this).parent();
    // etc...
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent